# Radius convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n} z^{n(n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I wish to show that the series

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n} z^{n(n+1)}$

Has radius of convergence $R=1$.

I know that if the series would have the form $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n z^n$ then $R=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$.

But the series has no a form like that.

Can you give me a hint to show that $R=1$?

Comment: Try the Root Test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.  $\root{n}\of n\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Oh, you mean to apply the Roor Test for the whole series not only the $a_n$'s, right?
Thanks to you and André Nicolas, it worked and $R=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you know why the domain of convergence of a series is a disk plus some points of the boundary, then it is easy to calculate the radius in this case.

For $z=1$, the series is convergent by the alternating series test. For any $\varepsilon>0$, I say the series $$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}(1+\varepsilon)^{n(n+1)}$$ is divergent, for the general term does not tend to zero. Try to show it yourself; in any case, an argument is below.

> By Bernoulli, the even terms are such that $\frac{(-1)^{2n}}{2n}(1+\varepsilon)^{2n(2n+1)}\geq\frac{1+2n(2n+1)\varepsilon}{2n}\gt (2n+1)\varepsilon,$ so the general term indeed does not tend to zero.

Answer (score 0):

If $|z| > 1,$ then $|z|^{n(n+1)}/n>|z|^n/n \to \infty.$ Hence the $n$th term does not approach $0,$ and the series diverges. If $|z|<1,$ then $|z|^{n(n+1)}/n \le |z|^n.$ Since $\sum |z|^n = 1/(1-|z|) < \infty,$ the series converges absolutely, hence converges. It follows that the radius of covergence is $1.$